# How can I place these row values to columns without looping?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image: My table]

I like to get something like this:

[image: My Result Table]

The rows starting with 'Property' will go to Property column.  Rows starting with 'Location' will go to 'Location' column, and rows starting with 'error' will go to 'ErrorMessage' column.  The table here is containing parent-child like data.  For example, Property X has a location 'abc' with two errors '1234' and '5678'.

Based on comments so far I am adding some more information.

Aaron Bertrand asked:
Q1.Can you absolutely rely on rowid being sequential?

A1.Rowid is sequentially increasing, but not always in same order of 1 though.

Lets look at an example. Property X starts at rowid = 1, Property Y at 8. Everything for Property X will be between rowid 1 to 7. If we go another level, Location abc starts at 2 and 'def' starts at 5. All errors for location 'abc' will be between rowid 3 to 4.

Q2. And is there only one set of data for any location / property combination? Or is it possible that row 15 is Property X again, row 16 is property abc again, etc.?

A2. There is only one set of data for Property-Location combination.  So if you find Property X - Location abc on row 2 you will not find it later some time on the table.

More information: The example here has only limited amount of rows.  The actual table has much more rows than this.

So far I have used WHILE loop do get my result.  I am just wondering if there is any alternative way of doing this without going through row by row.  I am using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Thats a terrible db design.  If you split it into 3 tales: property, location and error - then that would at least be a good start - then you'd not need to do any hideous rotation on unrelated data

Comment: Egads, why are you storing the data this way in the first place? What is tying this information together at all? The fact that everything on rowid x belongs to whatever property / location was last seen in rowid < x? Ugh.

Comment: The table is an import from a text file provided by 3rd party.  It is not part of any database.  The client wants a pivot from data of this text file.  My idea is to organise the data into the format I have described and then client can do whatever with it.

Comment: Y'all shouldn't always jump on the user for a bad data set, when it could easily be a 3rd party export or someone else's poor design.

Comment: How do you even import that in the right order?

Comment: @KyleHale so don't comment on bad design, ever? What if this is the person who designed the 3rd party export? I don't agree with that logic at all. People need to know when things are not right.

Comment: ...whether it was their design or not, and whether or not they're going to like it or want to hear it. Those comments are just as much for anyone else who happens on the question and is considering with, or currently dealing with, a similar design, and *does* have the power to fix it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Please re-read the fourth word in your comment, and re-read mine. It is one thing to point out bad design, it is another thing to "jump on the user." It is not a distinction without a difference.

Comment: My point was everyone assumes the user is perfectly okay with this design and not, you know, trying to turn it into a useful data set *with this very question.*

Comment: Are you paying the vendor for this file. If so reject the file. Get in contanct with the 3rd party and request they change their output in a way that's inteligable..

Comment: @KyleHale On the other hand, I have come across a ***ton*** of users who said, "I have this table..." and then, when their design was criticized, they actually *did* fix it. And thanked us for it. So I will err on the side of "maybe they can fix this." YMMV.

Comment: I think I should have explained a bit more about this to remove any confusion about the 'design'. A windows app produces these text error logs.  Client, in this project, ran this app several times and now has a bunch of separate text log files. Client likes to see overall situation and my manager promised a pivot table. So that is the long story short.

Comment: Can you absolutely rely on `rowid` being sequential?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it will sequentially increasing, not always in same order.  For example Property X starts at rowid = 1, Property Y at 8.  Everything for Property X will be between rowid 1 to 7. If we go another level, Location abc starts at 2 and 'def' starts at 5. All errors for location 'abc' will be between rowid 3 to 4.

Comment: And is there only one set of data for any location / property combination? Or is it possible that row 15 is Property X again, row 16 is property abc again, etc.?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, there is only one set of data for Property-Location combination, luckily!

Comment: is the Property, location and Error has same number of rows in original table ? also How does they link together ? which property value is linked to which location and which error ?

Comment: never-mind i should have read comments and edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 1 query. First split the data into three parts (Property, Location and Error) and determine the Parent ID's. Finally, use regular joins to create the result:

```
with P as (
  select ID, ColumnDesc 
  from MyTable P
  where columnDesc like 'Property %'
),
L as (
  select ID, ColumnDesc, (Select MAX(P.id) from P where P.ID<L.ID ) as ParentID 
  from MyTable L
  where columnDesc like 'Location %'
),
E as (
  select ID, ColumnDesc, (Select MAX(L.id) from L where L.ID<E.ID ) as ParentID 
  from MyTable E
  where columnDesc like 'error %'
)
select 
  P.ColumnDesc as Property,
  L.ColumnDesc as Location,
  E.ColumnDesc as Error
FROM p
JOIN L ON (L.ParentId = P.ID)
JOIN E ON (E.ParentID = L.ID)
ORDER BY P.ID, L.ID, E.ID
```

Comment: Thanks @user2970362.  This is doing it.  Just in case you are interested in the timing for this solution vs WHILE loop, it is 2 sec vs 1 min 22 sec!  Great Job!

Answer (score 0):

```
with ds as (
select 1 as rowid, 'Property X' as columnDesc
union
select 2 as rowid, 'Location abc' 
union
select 3 as rowid, 'error 1234' 
union
select 3 as rowid, 'error 3456' 
union
select 4 as rowid, 'Property Y' 
union
select 5 as rowid, 'Location abc' 
union
select 6 as rowid, 'error 1234' 
union
select 7 as rowid, 'Location def' 
union
select 8 as rowid, 'error 12' 


)

,

rnProperty as (
select row_number() over (order by rowid) as rn , * from ds
where
columnDesc like 'Property%'),

rnLocation as (
select row_number() over (order by rowid) as rn , * from ds
where
columnDesc like 'Location%')



select 
rn.columnDesc, rnL.columnDesc, ds2.columnDesc

from rnProperty rn 
left join rnProperty rn2 on rn2.rn = rn.rn + 1
left join rnLocation rnL on rnL.rowid > rn.rowid and rnL.rowid < isnull(rn2.rowId,100000)
left join rnLocation rnL2 on rnL2.rn = rnL.rn + 1
left join ds ds2 on ds2.rowid > rnL.rowid and ds2.rowid < isnull(rnL2.rowid,1000000) and ds2.columnDesc like 'error%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In the question I did not give the actual data, obvioulsy for data security reason.  The actual table contains around 100000 rows.  That's why although I have done it using WHILE loop, I am curious if it can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem in my opinion. Here's a solution in Oracle. I think it's the shortest one posted so far, just using a single query with two sub-queries.

```
WITH data1 AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS id,'Property X' AS columnDesc FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 2 AS id,'Location abc' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 3 AS id,'error 1234' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 4 AS id,'error 3456' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 5 AS id,'Property Y' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 6 AS id,'Location abc' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 7 AS id,'error 1234' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 8 AS id,'Location def' FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT 9 AS id,'error 12'FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d2.columnDesc,d3.columnDesc,d.columnDesc
FROM data1 d, data1 d2, data1 d3
WHERE d.columnDesc NOT LIKE 'Property%'
AND d.columnDesc NOT LIKE 'Location%'
AND d2.id < d.id
AND d2.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM data1
             WHERE columnDesc LIKE 'Property%' AND id < d.id)
AND d3.id < d.id
AND d3.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM data1
             WHERE columnDesc LIKE 'Location%' AND id < d.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

TSQL

```
WITH
source AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS id,'Property X' AS columnDesc
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id,'Location abc'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id,'error 1234'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS id,'error 3456'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS id, 'Location def'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS id,'error 1234'
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS id,'error 3456'
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS id,'Property Y'
  UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS id,'Location ab'
  UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS id,'error 12'
  UNION ALL SELECT 11 AS id,'error 56'
  UNION ALL SELECT 12 AS id,'Location de'
  UNION ALL SELECT 13 AS id,'error 12'
  UNION ALL SELECT 14 AS id,'error 56'
),
maxid AS
(
  SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM source
),
properties AS
(
  SELECT id, columnDesc FROM source WHERE columnDesc like 'Property%'
),
propertiesPlus AS
(
  SELECT id, columnDesc,
    isnull( (SELECT MIN(p2.id) FROM properties p2 WHERE p1.id < p2.id ),
    (SELECT maxid FROM maxid)) as nextid
  FROM properties p1
),
locations AS
(
  SELECT id, columnDesc FROM source WHERE columnDesc like 'Location%'
),
locationsPlus AS
(
  SELECT id, columnDesc,
    isnull( (SELECT MIN(l2.id) FROM locations l2 WHERE l1.id < l2.id ),
    (SELECT maxid FROM maxid)) as nextid
  FROM locations l1
),
errors AS
(
  SELECT id, columnDesc FROM source WHERE columnDesc like 'error%'
)
SELECT p.columnDesc as Property, l.columnDesc as Location, e.columnDesc as Error
FROM propertiesPlus p
  JOIN locationsPlus l ON l.id BETWEEN p.id and p.nextid
  JOIN errors e ON e.id BETWEEN l.id AND l.nextid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the `'error %'` rows and use `columnDesc` as `ErrorMessage`, then calculate `Property` as the latest `columnDesc` preceding the given row and matching the mask `'Property %'`, and similarly for `Location`. Here's the query I am talking about:

```
SELECT
  Property     = (SELECT TOP (1) columnDesc
                  FROM atable
                  WHERE rowid < main.rowid AND columnDesc LIKE 'Property %'
                  ORDER BY rowid DESC),
  Location     = (SELECT TOP (1) columnDesc
                  FROM atable
                  WHERE rowid < main.rowid AND columnDesc LIKE 'Location %'
                  ORDER BY rowid DESC),
  ErrorMessage = columnDesc
FROM atable AS main
WHERE columnDesc LIKE 'error %'
;
```